# Unified inbox shows twice on Thunderbird

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird

I'm using Thunderbird 24. If I show folders in Unified mode, my inbox folder shows up twice. If I choose the "All" folders mode, I see only one inbox.

The issue started when I was using Ubuntu 12.04, but now I'm on Fedora 19. (I have migrated the folders on /home). I do remember having it not-duplicated, but then it started while still on Ubuntu.

I noticed it when using the Converation plugin, but I had previously used the plugin without it happening. I have disabled the plugin and it persists.

## What I have tried

If I close Thunderbird, rename the `.thunderbird` folder on my `/home` to something else, then it will create a new config profile, I have to set up everything again, and then it works as expected, see images below:

### Before resetting

[image]
[image]

```
Unified               vs   All Folders
```

### After resetting

[image]
[image]

```
Unified               vs   All Folders
```

(I'm trying to avoid resetting the profile and creating a fresh new one, because the server -- MS Exchange -- doesn't support IMAP labels, so **I'd lose all the tags on my messages**, and I have organized it based on tags instead of folder).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Unified Folders were seriously deranged in Thunderbird 24.

See [Bug 490328](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=490328)
for all sort of problems with this feature when upgrading to version 24.

It seems like this problem might possibly not exist in Thunderbird 23,
so going back to it can be a temporary solution.
That is, if your problem is caused by the same bug.

You should in any case also report this bug to [Bugzilla@Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Comment: Weird, because if I reset my profile (in Thunderbird 24), create a blank new one and enter the IMAP settings I get the second image pair, the expected result with only a single inbox.

Comment: Your experience confirms that Thunderbird 24 breaks the Unified Folders of version 23. As far as my knowledge goes your choices are (1) to signal the bug and hope someone knows of a workaround, (2) skip version 24 in the hope this gets fixed in version 25, or (3) create a new profile in 24 and try to transfer the tags. This [link](http://mailtweak.mozdev.org/tweaks.html#tagtools) says that this is possible. I don't have your environment, so you will need to experiment, but it seems as if export/import the tags can be done by hacking the file prefs.js in the profile.